# How to connect to prestashop database with desktop java program

Tags: java, web-services, api, prestashop

I am a beginner with java and I can't find anything on my problem (wich is not a good sign...)

My objective would be to :

- Create a prestashop website
- Create a desktop java program that a customer of the prestashop website will be able to download
- In this program, ask the user to enter his email and password that he used to order on the prestashop website
- **Check if the user exists (with his password) and look for the list of products that he bought.**

Is it possible to do so ? If yes, how can I do it ?
I was thinking of maybe using the Prestashop API, but I don't know how...

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Easy. Simply use the REST API from Prestashop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The problem is that all Prestashop API examples that I find are in php... I don't know how to use it with JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating a web-service. This web-service will be a simple PHP file existing inside your PrestaShop directory.

You need to communicate with this file to perform desired actions. You can send and fetch data in JSON format (i.e. supported by both Java and PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do what you want, but you will require a Prestashop API Key to connect your java app with Prestashop webservices.

Find more info here: [Prestashop Webservices](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Servicehttp://)

Anyway, you dont need that user enter his password to know what product did he bought. Just with registered email address you can identify customer properly in Prestashop.

Good luck.